# How to use preview image or PDF from Google Drive, using API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm writting Web application to display content of Google Drive images and files, using API.
Currently, I can only see thumbnails of images/files (without login to Google drive).
If I want to preview the file, I need to be logged into Google drive and then I can use link returned by "webViewLink" and actually see the file.
I know I can click on folder or file on Drive and Share it, but I'm afraid that my customers will not be able to do that and it is complicated, anyway.
I already displaying Google dialog to customer where customer need to allow access to upload,delete etc. of files and now he can not preview the file???
Application is designed to display image/whatever to customer only, inside app only and not to sharing. With other words, I want to display images which he can see anyway if he is logged to Drive.
Is there any other option to allow customer to preview the file, if he already allowed full access previously?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorizing with OAuth **does not** automatically log you in. Users use their credentials to give their permission to create an access token, which needs to be used in any API calls. It does not imply that a browser session was created, that's a separate process.

You'll notice that the `webViewLink` is just the regular Drive URL with `/view` at the end. It's a page that requires the user to be signed in:

```
"webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/<FILE-ID>/view?usp=drivesdk",
```

I'm not aware of any methods to sign in the user at the same time they use OAuth, but if you send your `access_token` in an `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` header when trying to access the above URL you can see the preview without having to sign in. Depending on your platform I think implementing this would be tricky, and maybe not possible in Apps Script alone.

My recommendation as a workaround is to just use a full thumbnail. Don't know if you're aware of this, but the thumbnail URL has a `=s` parameter at the end that defines its height in pixels:

```
"thumbnailLink": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/<THUMB-ID>=s220",
```

You can change the default `=s220` at the end to a higher size or remove it completely to get pretty much the full size of the image or PDF page. This may be enough for your users to figure out what the file is.

Comment: Daniel, if "openid" is used inside scope, then user is also logged into Google account, in the same time as he use oAuth2.

Comment: That trick about `=s220` is SUPER helpful!